# Editing Answers

Tags: discussion

I came across this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12752140) in the review queue.  It's an edit to an answer.  In general, I've approved very few proposed answer edits unless it was just to fix formatting or typos, because even if the edits made the answer better, they clearly weren't the author's intent.

In this case, it's updating an existing answer because I'm guessing it's partially obsolete due to new versions of the software that have changed.

My question is, what is the criteria for expecting users to create *new* answers rather than editing existing ones?  Should I be more lenient in the types of edits I allow to answers?  Is making the answer better all that is required?

Answer (score 4):

I might have let this one go if it weren't for [another answer saying (kind of) the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22706743/1079354).

The main issue there is that information is being duplicated; a decent edit to the question you linked to might have made reference to this working only in older versions of the IDE, and the other answer being cleaned up to indicate that this works in newer versions of the IDE.

Comment: [*"Then refresh your pom.xml. That worked for me."*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26879486/366904) The wonders of bad kerning!